# Using regex replace with smarty template system?

Tags: php, html, regex, smarty

Here's what I currently have in my Smarty template:

```
<div class="tbl_pagination">
    {if $pager}{$pager->links}{/if}
<div>
```

My `{$pager->links}` will output this HTML:

```
<div class="tbl_pagination">
    <ul><li><a href="javascript:toPage(3)" title="previous page">Back</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:toPage(1)" title="page 1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:toPage(2)" title="page 2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:toPage(3)" title="page 3">3</a></li>
    <li class='active'>4</li>
    <li><a href="javascript:toPage(5)" title="page 5">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:toPage(6)" title="page 6">6</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:toPage(7)" title="page 7">7</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:toPage(5)" title="next page">Next</a></li>
    </ul></div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to replace two different things:

1. I want to completed remove `the title` attribute.
2. Whichever `li` has the class `active` needs to also have an `a href`.

Here's what I'd like it to look like:

```
<div class="tbl_pagination">
    <ul><li><a href="javascript:toPage(3)">Back</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:toPage(1)">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:toPage(2)">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:toPage(3)">3</a></li>
    <li class='active'><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:toPage(5)">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:toPage(6)">6</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:toPage(7)">7</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:toPage(5)">Next</a></li>
    </ul></div>
</div>
```

Is this possible to do in the Smarty template system using their replace function?

Comment: Can't you edit what `$pager->links` outputs, before smarty outputs it?

Comment: I can but I only actually need the changes I mentioned above done on one page - and there's multiple pages that use `$pager->links`

Comment: Actually I fixed the second issue by just replacing it in the PHP file.  But the first problem still needs a regex solution.

Comment: Do you really not have a better solution than using javascript for page navigation? What happens if someone wants to open a page in a new tab? Or they have JS disabled?

Comment: +1 for the nice syntax and clarity of your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned in your comments that you achieved (2) on your own, here's a solution for the first replace, with 2 methods:

1. You can use [regex_replace](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.regex.replace.tpl):

   `{$pager->links|regex_replace:'/title="[\w\s]+"/':""}`
2. Alternatively, you can use directly php's preg_replace, like this:

   `{'/title="[\w\s]+"/'|preg_replace:'':$pager->links}`

This might seem weird at first, but let me explain the syntax:

Smarty supports passing a variable/string to some php function using the `|` (pipe) symbol. However, additional parameters are then passed with the `:` (colon) parameter. This is consistent for the syntax of [Variable Modifiers](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.strip.tpl)

For example, if you wanted to count the letters on your string, you would do:

```
{$pager->links|strlen}
```

And if you wanted to see if a value `foo` is within an array `$bar` you would do:

```
{'foo'|in_array:$bar}
```

so, for a php function that looks like `func($arg1, $arg2, $arg3)`, this translates to `{$arg1|func:$arg2:$arg3}`

Needless to say the preferred method is (1), I only suggested the 2nd because, to my opinion, it is interesting to know.