# Hiding email domain using smarty

Tags: php, regex, smarty

We are using FormTools to manage client data in our organisation. Due to recent changes in security policy my employer has asked me to mask phone numbers and email addresses of the clients. I used custom fields module and created the fields to mask them by using following code

{$VALUE|substr:-4}

this works well for the phone numbers but now my employer has asked me to mask only the domain part of the email address

eg: email@xyz.com should be displayed as email@xxx.com

the above mentioned smarty variable $value contains the email address.

Comment: So, where did you get stuck? Please show the current code.

Comment: http://modules.formtools.org/custom_fields/?page=displaying_tab

this the module I used to create the masking field, display tab contains how the data is displayed. I only have {$VALUE|substr:-4} in "view field" there.

I am new to smarty and have no idea how to mask it.

Comment: Like [this](http://ideone.com/jh2AYB)?

Comment: I think it is possible through regex_replace but I dont know how.

Comment: So, `$smarty->assign('str', "email@xyz.com"); {$str}
{$str|regex_replace:"/(@)|(?!^)\\G\\w/":"$1x"}`. Syntax taken from [this documentation page](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.regex.replace.tpl).

Comment: @stribizhev I have following as my code now
{$value|regex_replace:"/(@)|(?!^)\\G\\w/":"$1x"}
it gives a blank output
am I doing it right?

Comment: It looks right, I just rely on the documentation for the syntax, but I do not know what the value your `$value` holds.

Comment: `$value` holds the email address in this case

Comment: Try `{$value|replace:'(@)|(?!^)\G\w':'$1x'}`. Or `{'/(@)|(?!^)\G\w/'|preg_replace:'$1x':$value}`.

Comment: @stribizhev the issue is resolved up to an extent, I am getting email.com instead of email@xxx.com

Comment: Try to use ``\`` instead of `$`: `{'/(@)|(?!^)\G\w/'|preg_replace:'\1x':$value}`. Perhaps, smarty is too smart and does not let the `$` through (maybe, it needs escaping?)

Comment: @stribizhev Thank you, the issue is resolved by `{'/(@)|(?!^)\G\w/'|preg_replace:'$1x':$value}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
{'/(@)|(?!^)\G\w/'|preg_replace:'$1x':$value}
```

The regex used is `(@)|(?!^)\G\w`. It does the following:

- `(@)` - matches and captures `@`
- `|` - or...
- `(?!^)\G\w` - an alphanumeric character (`\w`) after each successful match.

Thus, we find `@` first, and then we only match alphanumeric symbols right after it replacing all of them with `x` symbol. The `@` itself is restored in the result with the help of a back-reference `$1`.

Here is an [IDEONE PHP demo](http://ideone.com/jh2AYB)

The smarty syntax for using PHP functions is described in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26575900/3832970).